# How to set the table space of a sub select in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, tablespace

I have a rather large Insert Query, and upon running this my slow disks fill up towards 100% upon where I revive:

```
Transaction aborted because DBD::Pg::db do failed: ERROR:  could not write to hash-join temporary file: No space left on device
```

Sounds believable, I have a Fast drive with lots of space on it that i could use instead of the slow disk but I dont want to make the fast disk the default table-space or move the table im inserting into to the fast disk, I just want that data-blob that is generated as part of the insert query to be on the fast disk table-space. Is this possible is PostgreSQL and if so how?

version 9.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `temp_tablespaces` configuration directive.  See [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TEMP-TABLESPACES).

> Temporary files for purposes such as sorting large data sets are also
>   created in these tablespaces

You must [`CREATE TABLESPACE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtablespace.html) the tablespace(s) before using them in an interactive `SET temp_tablespaces` command.

`SET LOCAL temp_tablespaces` may be used to set it only for the current transaction.